# It's possible make an OCR in Python to check words

Tags: python, windows, firefox, ocr

in opened applications?

I want to automate firefox in some web page and I don't have a way to "know" if the page already load completely or if it still loading...

I was thinking about making an OCR to check the status bar... it's difficult ?

For example, when the word DONE appears at the status bar, the program continues to the next command...

Comment: I was thinking about it and, one solution to my problem, would be probably take an screenshot from the screen, store to the memory and run some ocr module on it... but how can I take a screenshot from a specified location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/ is what you want

Answer (score 4):

OCR is a terrible, terrible choice for something like this. Use OCR when you are encountering images with unknown text. If you are trying to automate Firefox, there's a billion better ways of doing so. Check out something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com) or any one of a hundred automation tools for Windows. Or write a custom Firefox extension. Either one of those will be far easier to implement, more reliable, and more performant than OCR.

Comment: the problem with external tools is that most of it doesn't tell you when the site stops loading, or done with the loading...

Comment: You could use external tools to hook into the Windows API to spot the "Done" message much easier than with OCR. Or write a simple Firefox extension to signal when the page loads.